# Perl - use related modules within a package hierarchy

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a number of related classes within the same namespace, but the classes can't seem to find each other.

I'm working within the namespace `Crypt::HSXKPasswd`. My `.pm` files are in the correct file paths in a folder `./lib` (`Crypt::HSXKPasswd` is defined in `./lib/Crypt/HSXKPasswd.pm` etc.).

Within my main module's constructor (`Crypt::HSXKPasswd->new`) I try to instantiate an object of type `Crypt::HSXKPasswd::Dictionary::Default`.

My test file is located in `.`, and has the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use lib './lib';
use Crypt::HSXKPasswd;

my $hsxkpasswd = Crypt::HSXKPasswd->new();
```

It fails to execute with the following error:

```
Can't locate Crypt::HSXKPasswd::Dictionary::Default in @INC (@INC contains: ./lib /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at lib/Crypt/HSXKPasswd.pm line 482.
```

Notice that `@INC` contains `./lib`. The following head command shows that the `.pm` file for the module is located within the correct path under `./lib`, and that it does define the correct package:

```
$ head -1 ./lib/Crypt/HSXKPasswd/Dictionary/Default.pm 
package Crypt::HSXKPasswd::Dictionary::Default;
$
```

If the `.pm` file exists, defines the module, and is located in the correct path relative to a folder in `@INC`, why is Perl not seeing it?

Comment: in your file `Crypt::HSXKPasswd` you need to `use Crypt::HSXKPasswd::Dictionary::Default;`

Comment: `Crypt::HSXKPasswd::Dictionary::Default` - the package name wasn't converted to file name. Could you please publish a couple lines around the use statement (before the change that fixed it)? Thank you.

Comment: @Dallaylaen - I don't have the broken code anymore, but it was a require directive rather than a use directive, and if memory serves it was using a string rather than a bare word, and might well explain the whole problem.

Comment: @BartB yes it does. `require "Foo::Bar";` will try to load a Foo::Bar literally. You might want to replace it with `use Module::Load; load "Foo::Bar"; ` - it should autodetect whether it's a file, or a package.

Comment: @Dallaylaen you should pop that into an answer, that way I can accept it and you can pick up the reputation your answer deserves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note `Crypt::HSXKPasswd::Dictionary::Default` in the error message - it wasn't converted into `Crypt/HSXKPasswd/Dictionary/Default.pm`, so Perl tried to load a *package* literally, and failed.

This may happen in use case like follows:

```
my $foo = "Foo::Bar";
require $foo; # tries lo load literal Foo::Bar
```

This can be overcome by using [Module::Load](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Load) which will autodetect whether you're going to load a module or file.

```
use Module::Load;

# later
my $foo = "Foo::Bar";
load $foo;
```

Or one can use a string eval:

```
my $foo = "Foo::Bar";
eval "require $foo" or die $@;
```

But note that `evil`ing strings may be dangerous, so check the variable twice twice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your current working directory is not where you think it is at the time the module is loaded. Something in one of your modules may be changing the current working directory. For example, I can reproduce the problem by having a module that looks like this:

```
package Crypt::HSXKPasswd;

BEGIN { chdir("/"); }

use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::HSXKPasswd::Dictionary::Default;

1;
```

Your problem likely isn't this straightforward, but you probably have a module somewhere in the chain doing something similar, whether through something as direct as that `BEGIN` statement or less obvious, as by changing a directory before a `require` statement. Given that your module is failing at line 482, it's probably not a `use` statement that's loading the module (those are usually listed at the top of a package), so I'd lean towards a `chdir()` initiated somewhere before a `require`.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I don't understand, changing from using `require` within the constructor only when `Crypt::HSXKPasswd::Dictionary::Default` was needed (only needed for some paths through the constructor), to just importing it with a `use` statement at the top of the file, fixed the problem.

I think the moral of the story is probably not to try to optimise too soon, and not to try to be too clever for your own good!

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30043596/1735796). The reason that works for you is that `require` happens at runtime, whereas `use` happens at compile time. Because your `use lib` statement references a relative path, if your working directory changes (which is to what the path is relative), then the script may no longer be able to load modules out of that relative path at runtime.